# Which windows rights for powershell's Get-WmiObject on remote PC?

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, permissions

When I run a simple powershell command on a remote PC such as

Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -computer Pc1

Some Pcs reply "Access denied", while other reply fine, but I can't get the difference.

Which rights are involved?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this ServerFault question [Which permissions/rights does a user need to have WMI access on remote machines?](https://serverfault.com/questions/28520/which-permissions-rights-does-a-user-need-to-have-wmi-access-on-remote-machines)

Answer (score 0):

Disable windows firewall first, to see if it's that simple; if so, you can narrow it down to individual ports.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this was a firewall issue.  The fact that some machines acquiesce, and others have the gaul to respond with a "Access denied" means the traffic is getting through to the target, and a response is getting back.

Comment: Reason I mentioned it is that I once inherited a network where half the users had the firewall enabled, the other half didn't.  I actually received access denied errors from the (WMI based) network monitoring software, which really wasn't what I expected, either.

Comment: Fair comment, I guess it pays it expect the unexpected!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a local admin on the target PC, and you need to be using those credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Non admins should be able to run PowerShell WMI queries if the WMI Control permissions are adjusted to allow access.

My research found the following...
See KB 325353 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393613(VS.85).aspx

On the target server:
Computer Management | WMI Control | Security Tab 
Highlight Root\cimv2 node
Click Security button
For EVERYONE group, check Remote Enable box or add a group and grant Remote Enable and Enable Account.

I have not had a chance to test these settings yet.  Pls verify on NON-PRODUCTION server first.

Comment: It is interesting, but unfortunately does not solve the problem.