# What rights should non-admin user have to run Get-WmiObject?

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-access, wmi

I am trying to monitor windows machine with the help of wmi and powershell remoting. I managed to successfully start remote session with that machine throught non-admin user account, but now I have a problem with running WMI queries. My user is in the following groups (I followed [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/44997/191426) to setup account for that user):

```
[192.168.173.206]: PS C:\Users\lpu\Documents> Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $env:username | Format-table name

name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Domain Users                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Performance Monitor Users                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Distributed COM Users                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Remote Management Users                                                                                                                                                                                                                        



____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
[192.168.173.206]: PS C:\Users\lpu\Documents> os_caption
Get-WmiObject : Access denied 
At line:2 char:6
+     (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Answer (score -1):

As my collegue told me, I need to turn off User Account Control.

You cold do this with the following commands, I got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573204/816449):

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system -Name EnableLUA -PropertyType DWord -Value 0 -Force
Restart-Computer
```