# Grant Remote Launch and Remote Activation privilege with powershell script

Tags: powershell, wmi, winrm

I'm trying to grant full WMI remote access to a domain user, just like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/28520/which-permissions-rights-does-a-user-need-to-have-wmi-access-on-remote-machines)

It works but I need to automate this process with powershell scripts, any ideas?

I can't find anything relevant on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Here's someone who wrote (and documented!) a [UserRights.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Grant-Revoke-Query-user-26e259b0) module that is just what you need. This will grant privileges to groups as well as individual users.

You can add users to a group with vanilla Powershell: [add-ADGroupMember](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617210.aspx)