# permissions for MSFT classes

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, permissions, wmi

Im trying to query MSFT classes under non-admin user

```
Windows PowerShell Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\john.doe> Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM MSFT_Disk" 
-Namespace Root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage Get-WmiObject : Access denied At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM MSFT_Disk"  -Namespace Root/Microsoft/Window ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

PS C:\Users\john.doe>
```

1. I did all the steps mentioned in [Which permissions/rights does a user need to have WMI access on remote machines?](https://serverfault.com/questions/28520/which-permissions-rights-does-a-user-need-to-have-wmi-access-on-remote-machines/) answer.
2. I can query other namespaces like CIMv2
3. I verified that 'Root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage' namespace security has all the checkboxes set for john.doe user (domain user)

It looks like Root/Microsoft/Windows/* namespace requires some additional permissions (I get access denied for MSFT_SmbConnection too for example) but I cannot figure out what permissions

Comment: Discovered that querying MSFT_Volume works fine

Comment: Granting SeTcbPrivilege  for the user fixes this issue in Windows 2016, but doesn't in 2012