# Retrieve Actions-property of an via group-policy mapped network drive on Windows-client

Tags: windows, group-policy, mappeddrive

is it possible to retrieve detailed informationen about mapped network drives, which are configured via group policy, on the client side? Especially i'm interested in the "Actions"-property:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc770902(v=ws.11)

Since i want to use this information in an automated script i prefer the registry key or maybe WMI-object which contains this information.

*Update 13.07.2020*: Since i want to use this in different environments, is there a possibility to gain access without special permissions (e.g. as answered here: serverfault.com/questions/28520/…)?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way, client side, is to use the WMI RSOP classes:

Take a look at the following namespace:

```
ROOT\RSOP\User\<SID>
```

In the following Class: `RSOP_PolmkrDriveSetting`, one instance represents one drive to map, the `name` is the letter of the drive, and `polmkrBaseInstanceXml` contains a XML representation of the preference item.

The property named `polmkrAction` in this XML content contains "C" if the action is "Create", "R" for "Replace", "U" for "Update", "D" for "Delete".

Note that this is not documented, so it may break or change at any time (unlikley, but still..)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the mentioned object contains the needed information. I confirmed this via WMI Explorer (https://github.com/vinaypamnani/wmie2/releases), but i need administrator-rights to gain access to the objects. Since i want to use this in different environments, is there a possibility to gain access without special permissions (e.g. as answered here: https://serverfault.com/questions/28520/which-permissions-rights-does-a-user-need-to-have-wmi-access-on-remote-machines)?